# Rails - Reset select

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

Inside my form I have two dropdown boxes.

```
<%= f.input :movie_code, input_html: { class: "ajax_select2", onchange: "$.movies.movieChanged(this)" } %>  

<%= f.label :actor_name, required: true %>
<%= f.select :actor_code, choices, {}, {id: "actor_code_element", class: "select2"} %>
```

when I change the value on my first dropdown the function movieChanged fetches the actors of the movie via ajax and re populates the second dropdown.

```
movieChanged: function(element) {
    var $this = $(element);
    url = '/movie/' + $this.val() + '/actors/';

    $.getJSON(url, null, function(data, status, xhr) {
      $('#actor_code_element').empty(); //empty the list of options
      $('#actor_code_element').prop("selected", false);
      $.each($(data), function(index, value) {
        var option = $('<option />');
        option.attr('value', value.id).text(value.text);
        $('#actor_code_element').append(option); //add option
      });
    });
  }
```

What I can't do is resetting the value of the second dropdown after one option was previously selected.

For example: I select Pulp Fiction movie and Samuel L Jackson and John Travolta appear. I select Samuel. Next I change the movie to ShawShank Redemption. I reset the list of actors, but the selected actor remains John Travolta. I want to de-select it and set it to null...

I was reading around and tried:

```
$('#actor_element').val('')
$('option', $('#category_code_element').attr('selected', false);
```

nothing works...

How can I do it?

EDIT: Now I realized there might be a select2ish way of doing things. I'm trying to change it's way of working and that's probably why it isn't working as expected...
thanks in advance.

Comment: I meant val(''). Updated the answer. What you told me works (the value is null after, but the item is still displayed).

Answer (score 1):

Empty the select and set attribute disabled and enable it when you want to.

Try this

```
$('#actor_element').empty().attr('disabled','disabled');
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/qb5nt/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#actor_element').val([])
```

Should properly reset the select.

Edit: Ah, missed that you used select2.

I'd test

```
$('#actor_element').trigger('change')
```

And see if that does the trick.